# Difference in から and 以来

Tags: word-choice

When do I use から and when 以来?  For example,

> 私はここで1:00以来働いています。

or

> 私はここで1時から待っています。

Does it matter?  Does it ever matter (provided から is being used to mean "since a given time")?

Comment: from ... ~から  -  since ... 〜以来

Answer (score 3):

Yes it matters, they are two different things. It also depends if you are just asking about から or ～てから.

The first one by itself (in the context of time) means "from/after" so

> 1時から = From 1 o'clock

～てから　means "after doing" something and I could see more the question of the difference with 以来 in this case. For example:

> 日本に来てからずっと仕事を探しています.

On the other hand, て以来 means

> since /ever since
> 「Ａて以来、Ｂ」 B should be a continuous action, current circumstances, or a habit. It cannot express the future. (See more [here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1370819))

So for example in the following sentences in the first you could use 以来 but in the second and third you could not:

> ・去年離婚して以来、ずっと独身です。
>
> ・来週（×以来　○以降）ずっと雨が降るらしい
>
> ・来週×以来　○以降ずっと雨が降るらしい

More on ～[てから](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-flashcard-18/). More on [以来 and 以降](http://jn2et.com/JLPT/ta-teiraiN2.html) (that as you notice is what you should use in those cases).